# VLC to put 2 videos together, output video has glitchy playback and seeking

Tags: command-line, video, vlc-media-player, video-editing, concatenation

I am trying to put two videos together (one after the other) using VLC.  I did manage to get an output video *with both original videos concatenated*<sub>(That was hard enough to figure out!)</sub>, but the output video has playback (at least in VLC) that is seriously wonky.

I can tell that both videos are there, but:

- there are long pauses in the video (though it looks like eventually all video is shown),
- the audio also cuts in and out (and it looks like *not* all audio is played), and
- when the video is not showing, the time seek bar is stuck, and sometimes it is stuck even when there is video playing.

(How can so much go wrong with such a simple operation?  I could understand it maybe messing up playback of just the *second* video, but the output file is very broken.)

This is what I did:

1. Place copies of the original videos in the same folder as vlc.exe
2. Run the Command Prompt with "Run as administrator"
3. Run this:

   > vlc out-3.ogv out-4.ogv --sout=#gather:standard{access=file,mux=ogg,dst="D:\concat.ogv"} --sout-keep

**How can I get a more usable output file?**

(From looking at many different websites, it looked to me like concatenating two videos is not possible from within the actual VLC GUI, and can only be done from the command line, but I would be happy with an answer for either, of course!

I would also be happy with some way of just **fixing** the video I already have.)

Comment: it depends on your video format in/out. I'd suggest a remux.

Comment: @Endoro in: out-3.*ogv* and out-4.*ogv*  out: concat.*ogv*  I am not trying to change the format.  Are you saying the gather operator only works on certain formats?  Also, isn't muxing (multiplexing) used to have things run in parallel (such as adding sound to video, or making two videos show in frames side-by-side)?  That is not what I am looking to do here.  ...or are you saying just the act of remuxing somehow tends to 'fix' glitchy files like this (just because it happens to straighten out the time markers or something)?  How would I remux a single file like this anyway?